# Submit option is not visible while creating Participant in marbles-network 0.1.7 tutorial (Cannot Scroll down)

Tags: javascript, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

> **System Specifications:** Screen Resolution: 1366*768, Browser: Google Chrome, Operating System: Windows 10 Pro

I am working with the **Hyperledger tutorial marbles-network 0.1.7** tutorial on Online Hyperledger Composer Playground. When I am creating a participant in the tutorial, **submit** button is not visible. Additionally, scrolling is disabled on this page.

I tried the workaround to enter in full screen mode in Chrome (F11 key) and then clicking submit. It would be good to introduce scrolling on this window as this problem will persist in lower resolution systems.

I have attached the screenshots of two cases mentioned above for reference:

**Normal View:**
[Normal View (Submit button not visible)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsMmU.jpg)

**Full Screen View:**
[Full Screen View (Submit button visible)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAumS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Chrome are you using? Can you please update to the latest version and try to reproduce? If the issue persists, please create an issue in GitHub:
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues

Comment: I am using Google Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (32-bit). I am still facing the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: I have created the issue https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2233 for it. Thanks !